# What does 'Global' do in "Vec<String, Global>"?

Tags: rust

I can't find information about 'Global' in Rust but have seen it used as in `Vec<String, Global>`. Is it a keyword or something else, and what does it do in the example?

Comment: It's the name of the allocator, i.e. the part of the library that is in charge of negotiating with the operating system to get more memory. Most languages won't let you change the allocator, but Rust does, it can be really useful for embedded, kernels or videogames.

See https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/struct.Global.html .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an [allocator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.Allocator.html).

Sometimes, you do not want to allocate the memory of the `Vec` (or the `String`, or any other collection) using the [global allocator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/alloc/#the-global_allocator-attribute), but using some other allocator. It may be an arena allocator, or other kind of allocator better suited for this specific allocation.

Rust is [in the process](https://github.com/rust-lang/wg-allocators) of adding allocators to all standard library collections (currently unstable). Those allocators allow you to change the allocation strategy for some collection. [`Global`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/alloc/struct.Global.html) is the default allocator, and it allocates using the global allocator.